# Reload ActiveMQ Artemis web-interface

Tags: activemq-artemis

Tell me how you can restart the web without restarting the application? Management.xml needs to be reloaded for the new roles to apply. We couldn't find the command in the documentation.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles defined int the `management.xml` are only loaded at start time, see https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.27.0/artemis-cli/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/cli/commands/Run.java#L85